# index out of range uitableview in swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, swift3, swifty-json

I did the following screen which have 5 sections; in the first 4 sections I will use an array to show some information and the last section I will use it to show a gallery with a second array.

Normally in the method numberOfRowsInSection I was returning "return 5" and my screen show like the first image, when I changed to return self.obj_empresa?.count ?? 0, only shows the first sections like the second image. How can I solve this problem:

My code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //Muestra el # de celdas a mostrar
        //return 5 before showed the 5 sections
        return self.obj_empresa?.count ?? 0
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.infoEmpresaCell, for: indexPath) as! InfoEmpresaCell
            cell.lbl_nombreEmpresa.text = self.obj_empresa?[indexPath.item].nombre_emp
            cell.lbl_sloganEmpresa.text = "Subtitle"
            cell.iv_perfilEmpresa.layer.cornerRadius = 10
            cell.iv_perfilEmpresa.layer.masksToBounds = true
            cell.selectionStyle = .none

            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.redesSocialesEmpCell, for: indexPath) as! RedesSocialesEmpCell
            cell.iv_facebook.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            let singletap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(visitar_facebook(singletap:)))
            cell.iv_facebook.addGestureRecognizer(singletap)

            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.ubEmpCell, for: indexPath)
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.descEmpCell, for: indexPath) as! DescEmpCell
            cell.lbl_descEmpresa.text = "Description"
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }else if indexPath.row == 4 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.promoEmpCell, for: indexPath) as! PromoEmpCell
            cell.selectionStyle = .none
            return cell
        }
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
```

When I return 5 in my numberOfRowsInSection and I set this `cell.lbl_nombreEmpresa.text = self.obj_empresa?[indexPath.item].nombre_emp 
I get this "error index out of range" in my cellForRowAt indexPath but if I return this self.obj_empresa?.count ?? 0  and I set this`cell.lbl_nombreEmpresa.text = self.obj_empresa?[indexPath.item].nombre_emp

I don't have error but my screen only show like 2nd image

first image
[image]

second image

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: you are Correct my friend Thanks :D

Comment: great! accept my answer, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you clearly aren't implementing cellForRowAt correctly. you need to use indexPath.section in your conditionals as well. Also make sure you are implementing numberOfSections data source method.